# Pipelining POST requests with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests, http-pipelining

Assuming that I can verify that a bunch of `POST` requests are in fact logically independent, how can I set up HTTP pipelining using `python-requests` and force it to allow `POST` requests in the pipeline?

Does someone have a working example?

P.S. for extra points, how to handle errors for outstanding requests if pipeline suddenly breaks?

P.P.S. `grequests` is not an option in this case.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by a *pipeline*? Are you talking about [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) here? *Why* is `grequests` not an option?

Comment: Note the `requests` does [not support HTTP pipelining](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1394); using `grequests` would only ever be an approximation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, my google-fu hath failt me... Please convert that into an answer for acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requests` library [does not support HTTP pipelining](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1394).

You can *approximate* pipelining by using `grequests` which makes it easier to run many requests in parallel, but each parallel request would still use a new TCP connection.

(`requests` does pool connections, keeping the TCP connection open if the remote server permits this, but that only helps for sequential connections, and request and response still have to alternate).

Answer (score 3):

Pipelining requests can be done with the builtin httplib, but only by accessing the connection and response objects below their public interface.  [This snippet](https://gist.github.com/coady/f9e1be438ba8551dabad) demonstrates.

Edit: updated version for Python3: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/52#issuecomment-109756116