# Multiple requests over single connection with Python

Tags: python, http, https, tcp, python-requests

When I download a file using single request I do the following:

```
session = requests.Session()
params = {'fd': 1, 'count': 1024, 'auth': 'auth_token'}
r = session.get('https://httpbin.org/bytes/9', params=params)

print(r.content)
# b'\xb3_\\l\xe2\xbf/:\x07'
```

How can I do multiple requests without waiting for an answer?

Server api docs says:

> You can push multiple requests over single connection without waiting
> for answer, to improve performance. The server will process the
> requests in the order they are received and you are guaranteed to
> receive answers in the same order. It is important however to send all
> requests with "Connection: keep-alive", otherwise the API server will
> close the connection without processing the pending requests.

They are talking about one thread and multiple requests without waiting for an answer. I suppose it is called `HTTP pipelining`.

How can I do this with Python Requests library?

A similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29077516/11713857) suggests using parallel calls which is not the case for my question. It also says: "`requests` does pool connections, keeping the TCP connection open". How can I implement this?

Can I use any other synchronous library, if it's not possible for `requests`?

Comment: you can use aiohttp library

Comment: I suppose they are talking about HTTP pipelining.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipelining POST requests with python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077275/pipelining-post-requests-with-python-requests)

Comment: @Klaus D. Thanks. But this answer was written 5 years ago. Are you sure that there is no solution for this?

Comment: May be you are looking into this - https://pythonhosted.org/dugong/tutorial.html#pipelining-with-coroutines

Comment: The Github issue is still closed, for 7 years.

Comment: Async calls do not guarantee the order of requests. TCP does that.

Comment: Sorry, my answer there still stands; a [draft HTTP pipelining pull request for urllib3](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1074) was closed 2 years ago, so there doesn't appear to be an option in sight if you want to use requests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Thank you. Can you suggest any synchronous Python library for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get several pages in parallel, without threads. It exploits HTTP pipelining by resetting the state(private variable!) of `HTTPSConnection` to trick it into sending the next request ahead of time.

```
from http.client import HTTPSConnection, _CS_IDLE
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse


def pipeline(host, pages, max_out_bound=4, debuglevel=0):
    page_count = len(pages)
    conn = HTTPSConnection(host)
    conn.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
    responses = [None] * page_count
    finished = [False] * page_count
    content = [None] * page_count
    headers = {'Host': host, 'Content-Length': 0, 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'}

    while not all(finished):
        # Send
        out_bound = 0
        for i, page in enumerate(pages):
            if out_bound >= max_out_bound:
                break
            elif page and not finished[i] and responses[i] is None:
                if debuglevel > 0:
                    print('Sending request for %r...' % (page,))
                conn._HTTPConnection__state = _CS_IDLE  # private variable!
                conn.request("GET", page, None, headers)
                responses[i] = conn.response_class(conn.sock, method=conn._method)
                out_bound += 1
        # Try to read a response
        for i, resp in enumerate(responses):
            if resp is None:
                continue
            if debuglevel > 0:
                print('Retrieving %r...' % (pages[i],))
            out_bound -= 1
            skip_read = False
            resp.begin()
            if debuglevel > 0:
                print('    %d %s' % (resp.status, resp.reason))
            if 200 <= resp.status < 300:
                # Ok
                content[i] = resp.read()
                cookie = resp.getheader('Set-Cookie')
                if cookie is not None:
                    headers['Cookie'] = cookie
                skip_read = True
                finished[i] = True
                responses[i] = None
            elif 300 <= resp.status < 400:
                # Redirect
                loc = resp.getheader('Location')
                responses[i] = None
                parsed = loc and urlparse(loc)
                if not parsed:
                    # Missing or empty location header
                    content[i] = (resp.status, resp.reason)
                    finished[i] = True
                elif parsed.netloc != '' and parsed.netloc != host:
                    # Redirect to another host
                    content[i] = (resp.status, resp.reason, loc)
                    finished[i] = True
                else:
                    path = urlunparse(parsed._replace(scheme='', netloc='', fragment=''))
                    if debuglevel > 0:
                        print('  Updated %r to %r' % (pages[i], path))
                    pages[i] = path
            elif resp.status >= 400:
                # Failed
                content[i] = (resp.status, resp.reason)
                finished[i] = True
                responses[i] = None
            if resp.will_close:
                # Connection (will be) closed, need to resend
                conn.close()
                if debuglevel > 0:
                    print('  Connection closed')
                for j, f in enumerate(finished):
                    if not f and responses[j] is not None:
                        if debuglevel > 0:
                            print('  Discarding out-bound request for %r' % (pages[j],))
                        responses[j] = None
                break
            elif not skip_read:
                resp.read()  # read any data
            if any(not f and responses[j] is None for j, f in enumerate(finished)):
                # Send another pending request
                break
        else:
            break  # All responses are None?
    return content


if __name__ == '__main__':
    domain = 'en.wikipedia.org'
    pages = ['/wiki/HTTP_pipelining', '/wiki/HTTP', '/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection']
    data = pipeline(domain, pages, max_out_bound=3, debuglevel=1)
    for i, page in enumerate(data):
        print()
        print('==== Page %r ====' % (pages[i],))
        print(page[:512])
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I use existing connection that was created with `requests.Session()` instead of creating a new connection `conn = HTTPSConnection(host)`?

Comment: No, you can use only HTTPSConnection (or HTTPConnection), because this code uses it’s private variable (state).  And you should definitely check if it suits your tasks

Comment: I thought that `requests.Session` creates an `HTTPSConnection` under the hood. Is it wrong?